Extracting entries in a dataframe corresponding to n smallest positive values and n largest negative values of a certain variable in r
Imagine I have a table like the following one.
set.seed(12)
table = 
  data.frame(
    value = rnorm(n = 10), 
    par = runif(n = 10, min = - 1, max = 1)
  )

How can I extract the entries of value and par that correspond to the two smallest values of par above zero and the two biggest ones below zero? What I would like to obtain is something like
out = 
  data.frame(
    value = c(-0.2722960, -0.1064639, -0.3153487, 0.4280148),
    par = c(-0.464112814, - 0.121141350, 0.009535904, 0.339638592)
  )

I would appreciate if this could be done using dplyr so to be able to do it for bigger dataframes with grouping variables.

Just in case,  you should definitely consider your chances (and consequences) of having 0-values for par,  I really like how Adriano addresses that.

If you include par >= 0 to your grouping, you can select 2 minimum absolute values with slice_min(abs(par), n = 2):
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
set.seed(12)
table = 
  data.frame(
    value = rnorm(n = 10), 
    par = runif(n = 10, min = - 1, max = 1)
  )

table |> 
  group_by(pos = par >= 0) |>
  slice_min(abs(par), n = 2) |>
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>    value      par pos  
#>    <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>
#> 1 -0.106 -0.121   FALSE
#> 2 -0.272 -0.464   FALSE
#> 3 -0.315  0.00954 TRUE 
#> 4  0.428  0.340   TRUE

Created on 2024-04-25 with reprex v2.1.0

Another alternative:
# Toy data `my_table` at the end
aux <- my_table$par[my_table$par != 0] %>% 
  split(sign(.)) %>% 
  sapply(\(x) head(x[order(abs(x))], 2))

my_out <- my_table[my_table$par %in% aux, ]
rm(aux)

Input, output:
# Input
> arrange(my_table, par)
        value          par
1  -0.9567445 -0.804293921
2  -0.6282552 -0.622826146
3  -1.9976421 -0.564353914
4  -1.4805676 -0.563265665
5  -0.2722960 -0.464112814 # 
6  -0.1064639 -0.121141350 # 
7   9.0000000  0.000000000 # The presence of zero doesn't affect the output
8  -0.3153487  0.009535904 # 
9   0.4280148  0.339638592 # 
10 -0.9200052  0.419660932
11  1.5771695  0.575672695

# Output
> my_out
       value          par
1 -0.2722960 -0.464112814
2 -0.1064639 -0.121141350
3 -0.3153487  0.009535904
4  0.4280148  0.339638592

Toy data:
my_table <- structure(list(
  value = c(
    -1.48056759491936, 1.57716947155863, -0.956744479084269, -0.920005247558641, 
    -1.99764209693134, -0.27229604424923, -0.315348711467784, -0.628255236517538, 
    -0.106463884872094, 0.428014802202354, 9), 
  
  par = c(
    -0.56326566496864, 0.575672694947571, -0.804293920751661, 0.419660932384431, 
    -0.564353913534433, -0.464112814050168, 0.00953590357676148, -0.622826146427542, 
    -0.121141349896789, 0.339638591744006, 0)), 
  
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))


What about filtering for values above 0, sorting the values and taking the first two rows?
library(dplyr)

out <- table %>%
  filter(par > 0) %>%     
  arrange(par) %>%         
  head(2) %>%               
  bind_rows(                
    table %>% 
      filter(par < 0) %>%     
      arrange(desc(par)) %>%  
      head(2)                 
  )

> out
       value          par
1 -0.3153487  0.009535904
2  0.4280148  0.339638592
3 -0.1064639 -0.121141350
4 -0.2722960 -0.464112814

